# Error Saving Data from Unbound DGV to Database

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 `Datagridview` ,The first `dgv` is unbound and the second is bound, when I pass the data from unbound `dgv` to bound `dgv` i get the error

```
vshost.exe has stopped working
```

It works when only one row is copied but when it is two or more rows I get the error.

Here's my code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim cellvalue1 As String = ""
Dim cellvalue2 As String = ""
Dim cellvalue3 As String = ""
Dim cellvalue4 As String = ""
Dim cellvalue5 As String = ""

For i = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
    cellvalue1 = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Column1").Value.ToString
    cellvalue2 = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Column2").Value.ToString
    cellvalue3 = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Column3").Value.ToString
    cellvalue4 = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Column4").Value.ToString
    cellvalue5 = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Column5").Value.ToString
    Dim constr As String = "insert into Table1 ([Food No], [Food Name], [Amount], [Quantity],[Total]) VALUES (@f1, @f2,@f3,@f4,@f5)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(constr, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", cellvalue1)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", cellvalue2)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f3", cellvalue3)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f4", cellvalue4)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f5", cellvalue5)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

Comment: Sorry but this code doesn't _pass the data from unbound dgv to bound dgv_ this code tries to insert all the rows from _DataGridView1_ into a database table named _Table1_ Where is the code that creates the problem? Or what is exactly the problem? Did you have some more meaningful error message?

Comment: Debug your code in visual studio so that you get the actual exception that happens and the associated message. This will most likely tell you or us what's going on.

Comment: Fix gramma and format

Comment: `It works when only one row is copied but when it is two or more rows I get the error.`  One row would mean your loop would look like this:  `For i = 0 to -1`, meaning it would just skip the loop entirely since it's not stepping backwards.